# Is there any way to make a custom route in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# MVC, 
This is my default RouteConfig File,

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

When I run my project `http://localhost:50382` it redirects the default home index method.

How  can I build custom url like `http://localhost:50382/somestringcode` and call a specific ActionMethod. Something Like a custom route that points to specific ActionMethod and the stringcode will be passed as parameter.

```
public ActionResult Method1( string code)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: There are lots of examples on this if you do a quick google search.  Try something, and if it is not what you expect, ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this, where controller1 is the controller name that contains Method1, and make sure you place this first, and leave the original route config, so when it doesn't match this route, it will use default route. 
Please note this is bad practice, and it will fail in case route is trying to access default action for a controller "Index" as @stephen mentioned in the comments below, and that's why I would suggest adding a prefix ex "Action1" to the route.

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "Method1",
    url: "Action1/{code}",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller1", action = "Method1", code = "default"}
);
```

Comment: Thank you , you solved my problem :)

Comment: Wrong - all the other routes would fail. If a user enters `../Home` or `../Products` or anthing with one segment, if would that method instead of the intended `Index` method of those controllers

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenMuecke , I am not sure how I missed this, usually I would suggest appending something to the route, something like `"Method1/{code}"` but I follow his preference, and it is very bad practice, and it will fail as you mentioned.

Comment: Adding a prefix would be fine, otherwise you need a route constraint as per the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is `attribute routing`. That means specifying URL routes explicitly.
First, you need to enable it

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then add `Route` attribute to desired action:

```
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Method1( string code)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Since `code` parameter is simple type, it will be searched in request URL.